# Running a script for certain days

Tags: php, time, cron

I am developing a php script, which should run a shell script for every 20 mins for one 10 days.

I did explored the option of crontab but, crontab gives duration or specific time of every day.
It does not have option for running script every 20 mins for 10 days continuously.

If anybody has better option kindly, suggest.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your [crontab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#Predefined_scheduling_definitions):

```
*/20 * * * * bash /path/to/your/script.sh
```

Then remove it after 10 days.

Better yet, have your script check the current date and send you an email when it's 10 days from now to remind you to remove it.

You could also just have the script remove the line from the crontab (or just remove the crontab file if it's only got this one line) after 10 days.

Comment: I have doubt here, shouldn't I be running shell script in crontab, as shell script is the one that needs to be run every 20 mins, php script is only calling the shell script, I do not want php script to be running every 20mins.
Also, what if I have to run concurrently, multiple shell script with different duration ?

Comment: ah sorry @ajayramesh, i misread that part of your question—yes, you should put the path to the shell script in the crontab if that's the script you want to run. i've updated my answer to reflect this. and yes, you can put as many scripts in your crontab as you want. you can even set them all to run at the same time, if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with everyone else use crontab, then on your php file you could do this:

```
if(time() > strtotime('2013-08-01 00:00:00 +10 days')) {
    die();
}
```

Comment: the script will, of course, still run every 20 minutes—it just won't do anything.

Comment: Correct, but if you can't get in and delete the crontab at exactly that time, this will at least prevent the code from running until you can.

Comment: I do not want to prevent the code from running, because, similarly, I want to run concurrently, multiple scripts with different duration times, like 
    foo.sh 10days
    bar.sh 15days
    hello.sh 20days
concurrently. I cannot afford to stop the code from running.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `at` command, which will run the command specified at the specified time.  Note you will have to do your own calculation to determine each run time, and you'll wind up with a seed script like this:

```
$ for i in {0..720}; do echo 'php the-command.php' | at now + $(($i * 20)) minutes; done
```